# Exposing only some inherited methods in the derived class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I stumbled across an interview question related to OOPS. Here is the question:
There is a base class `A` with 5 methods. Now how should I design the class such that if a class `B` inherits class `A`, only 3 methods are exposed. And if a class `C` inherits class `A`, the rest of the 2 methods are exposed.

Any thoughts ??

Comment: protected and private

Comment: Is "don't do that" an allowed answer to an interview question?

Comment: There is no such thing.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question; try posting it in its original form instead of rephrasing it.

Comment: @svinja Maybe this is the right question. You know people ask such dumb questions interview just to see how the candidate answers.

Comment: Maybe using the internal keyword on 2 methods on class A.  Class B would then need to be in a seperate assembly, and class C in the same assembly?

Comment: @jrahhali You don't need inherit `C` from `A` to do that.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel although it's tagged in C#, I just want to know if its possible in any language like C++ or objective C

Comment: I think it was a trick question. You shouldn't preseve the hierarchy of the classes. Maybe you just should use interfaces instead.

Comment: exposed as public or exposed internally to B to where B can't call 2 methods of A

Comment: oh I guess I mis-read the last line of the question that's like split inheritance or something crazy

Comment: Does `new public void Foo()` counts as "exposing" `protected void Foo()`?

Answer (score 4):

if `A` is partial and you have 2 namespaces then:

```
namespace the_impossible
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        b.m1();
        b.m2();
        b.m3();

        c.m4();
        c.m5();
    }
}

namespace A_1
{
    public partial class A
    {
        public  void m1() { }
        public  void m2() { }
        public  void m3() { }
    }
}

namespace A_2
{
    public partial class A
    {
        public void m4() { }
        public void m5() { }
    }
}

class B : A_1.A 
{

}

class C : A_2.A
{ 

}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It should not be possible in *any* object-oriented language, otherwise it would break the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  Substituting a `B` for an `A` should not reduce its correctness (meaning methods should not suddenly be unavailable)

However, there is still some ambiguity in the question that allows for some "out-of-the-box" thinking.  Here are questions I would pose back to the interviewer:

- What do you mean by "exposed"?
- Do the 5 methods in A have to be public?
- Does the "exposition" by C need to be implicit or can the be explicitly exposed (e.g. pass-through)

Based on those answers you could either come up with possible options using `internal`, explicit interface implementations, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if we don't inherit instead let' say. I have a  class A with 5 or more methods. I want to add new methods to the class A and make it available exclusively to certain other classes(may be inherit or via some other concept). Is to possible to design something like that using OOPS concept.

Comment: Sure- you can encapsulate A and only expose what you want to, but that's very different from inheritance.

Comment: Ok I guess that's what it is then. An example would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a trick or even dumb question. To achieve this, we must break the Liskov substitution principle. You shouldn't preseve the hierarchy of the classes.

Maybe you just should use interfaces instead:

```
public class A {} //why we even need this class?

public class B : A, I3Methods
{
    public void Method1() { }
    public void Method2() { }   
    public void Method3() { }
}

public class C : A, I2Methods
{
    public void Method4() { }
    public void Method5() { }
}

public interface I3Methods
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
    void Method3();
}

public interface I2Methods
{
    void Method4();
    void Method5();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to have them all private in **A** and then expose them through encapsulation in **B** and **C**... But they are not exposed, only executed... So it is half right.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that's impossible.

But to give an approximate answer:

Make 3 methods in A virtual, then implement them in B. Then override those 2 methods in C.

Comment: The 2 "hidden" A methods will still be exposed through B; they just aren't overidden.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody says that the 5 methods of class A should be exposed when writing them. In `C#` you could simply write 5 protected methods in class A and expose those you wish to be accessible by writing some hiding methods with the [new modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) like this - although this wouldn't actually expose the methods directly they are merely wrapped.

```
class A
{
    protected void M1() { }
    protected void M2() { }
    protected void M3() { }
    protected void M4() { }
    protected void M5() { }
}

class B : A
{
    public new void M1()
    {
        base.M1();
    }

    public new void M2()
    {
        base.M2();
    }

    public new void M3()
    {
        base.M3();
    }

}

class C : A
{
    public new void M4()
    {
        base.M4();
    }
    public new void M5()
    {
        base.M5();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your comments, you mentioned that you were interested if this could be done in any other language.  You can kind of do it in C++ through the use of the [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/was37tzw.aspx) keyword.  So, starting with class A:

```
class A {
public:
    int Method1() {     return 1;   }
    int Method2() {     return 2;   }
    int Method3() {     return 3;   }
    int Method4() {     return 4;   }
    int Method5() {     return 5;   }
};
```

Then you define class B, using private inheritance (essentially you can't auto cast from B to A and all public methods in A become private methods in B).

```
class B: private A {
public:
    // We want to expose methods 1,2,3 as public so change their accessibility
    // with the using keyword
    using A::Method1;
    using A::Method2;
    using A::Method3;

};
```

Do the same for class C, exposing the other two methods instead:

```
class C: private A {
public:
    using A::Method4;
    using A::Method5;

};
```

Or if you're supposed to expose all the methods through C, simply use public inheritance and everything exists:

```
class C: public A {
public:

};
```

For usage:

```
B *b = new B();
b->Method1();  // This works, Method1 is public
b->Method4();  // This fails to compile, Method4 is inaccessible
```

The reason I said kind of above is because you can work around it by explicitly casting the instance of B to an A:

```
A *brokena = b;  // This wouldn't compile because the typecast is inaccessible

A *a = (A*)b;    // This however does work because you're explicitly casting
a->Method4();    // And now you can call Method4 on b...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is to late to respond. Just thought of sharing my thoughts:

Define Class A as a base class.
Have intermediate child classes A1 -> M1,M2,M3 and A2 -> M4, M5 deriving from Class A

Now, you can have 
1) Class B inheriting A1
2) Class C inheriting A2

These two classes are still derived from Class A.

And also we are not breaking liskov substitution principle.

Hope, this gives clarity.